# Evitar saltos en numeración de campo autoincremental

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla con un campo **ID** (*Primary Key*) *Autoincremental Not NULL*.
El asunto es que no me había percatado que al realizar los inserts la numeración sufre saltos haciendo que los **ID**'s no sean consecutivos.

Utilizo Xampp con MySQL 5.0.12.

Leí que seteando `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` al valor 1 se podía lograr el correlativo deseado. Pero no funciona. Incluso probé todas las configuraciones:

`innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0` (modo de bloqueo "tradicional")
`innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 1` (modo de bloqueo "continuo")
`innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2` (modo de bloqueo "intercalado")

Existe algún modo de lograr que el autoincremental funcione de manera correlativa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te está sucediendo es que los `INSERT` fallidos de registros que incumplen alguna clave, ya sea `UNIQUE` o `FK`, incrementan el `id` aunque no se haya llegado a insertar nada.

Lo primero que te diría es que realmente tu problema no existe porque el número de un `id`, mientras sea único, debería darte exactamente igual. Si lo que necesitas es un etiquetado correlativo, deberías crearte un campo para ese fin y gestionarlo como corresponda.

Si el TOC te supera, siempre puedes ajustar el `id` tras cada inserción y así soslayar el inconveniente de las inserciones fallidas con:

```
SELECT MAX(id_tabla)+1 FROM tabla;
```

Y usar ese dato en:

```
ALTER TABLE tabla AUTO_INCREMENT=n;
```

Comment: Tengo una tabla que necesita reiniciar el __ID__ en cada proceso mensual, para ello agregué un Trigger en el Insert con esta sentencia, que funciona `set new.id=(SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM tabla)` pero el primer registro inicia con 0 (cero) cómo hago para que inicie en 1?

Comment: Con un `SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id),0)+1 FROM tabla`, al tener la tabla vacía, el `MAX(id)` es un `NULL` y, como una `PK` es necesariamente `NOT NULL`, por eso te pone un cero en el nuevo `id`

Answer (score 1):

prueba con esta configuracion:

```
SET auto_increment_increment=1;
```

Espero que te funcione.

Comment: Gracias por responder, tu colaboración es bienvenida. Sin embargo, te invito a leer [answer] y a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas un poco más el funcionamiento de [es.so]. Tu respuesta parece más un comentario, sería de mucha utilidad, no sólo para quien pregunta sino para todos aquellos que tengan un problema similar, que argumentes un poco más tu respuesta, explicando el porqué y cómo solucionar el problema y algún enlace a la documentación oficial. Ojo que sólo un enlace tampoco es un argumento sólido, la idea es que puedas expresar la parte esencial de dicha documentación aquí. Saludos